# What header should I import for unity plugin

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, plugins

I installed NativeShare plugin. I created my own script. I want to share some site.

```
NativeShare().SetText("http://somesite.com").Share();
```

NativeShare not found. What header should I import?

link on plugin [link on plugin](https://assetstore.unity.com/packages/tools/integration/native-share-for-android-ios-112731)

Comment: How can we suggest a fix when we don't know anything about this plugin you mention? Do you have a link for it? Does it have any docs?

Comment: shouldn't you use `new NativeShare().SetText...` ?

Comment: @Cid Who knows, it could be the class inherits from an object that contains a `NativeShare` method. It could be a namespace of its own. We simply cannot answer.

Comment: The documentation linked for that plugin even says you should be using `new NativeShare()..`

Comment: @DavidG, I updated a plugin link. Readme file doesn't have information about what header should I import.

Comment: Please read the documentation closely next time, there was really no need for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not a matter of header. From [this file](https://github.com/yasirkula/UnityNativeShare/blob/master/Plugins/NativeShare/NativeShare.cs) I see the Plugin does not use any namespace, so (as already suggested by Cid in the comments) you just need to instantiate the class.

```
var nativeShare = new NativeShare();
nativeShare.SetText("http://somesite.com").Share();
```

You could also do it in one line.
`new NativeShare().SetText("http://somesite.com").Share();`